# Integration Google Calendar API with Apache OLTU

Tags: java

I'm trying to integrate the Google Calendar API using OLTU libraries.
When I try to execute the code request 1st step of OAuth2 dance, I receive an exception like the following:

```
19-Nov-2018 18:32:12.488 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Main Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception
```

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "reason" : "unauthorized"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
  "status" : "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}

I'm developing a portlet and my code is:

```
OAuthClientRequest request = OAuthClientRequest.authorizationProvider(OAuthProviderType.GOOGLE)
                                .setClientId("<my clientID>")
                                .setRedirectURI("http://localhost:8080/c/portal/google_login?cmd=token")
                                .setResponseType(OAuth.OAUTH_CODE)
                                .setScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar")
                                .buildQueryMessage();

        request.setHeader(OAuth.HeaderType.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        System.out.println("Location URI: "+request.getLocationUri());
```

Could someone give me any tips to solve this issue?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow :) Have you followed the links in the error message, or otherwise looked up a "how to" on authenticating in Google's API's? The error is fairly clear: you need to use a token, cookie, or other credential to authorize your API request

Comment: I'm doing a token request as the first step to implement the OAuth dance.
After as the second step I can use the token to ask the access token. from 
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/oltu-user/201503.mbox/%3CA562FE5D3662044186474F4174F11DAE13044C639F@iowajhnex126.iowa.gov.state.ia.us%3E